# Qt 6.2.0, Qt3D. Cannot apply a texture to an object

Tags: c++, qt, qt3d

I do not know how to apply a texture to an object. I tried like this but it does not work:

```
        Qt3DRender::QTextureLoader *textureLoader = new Qt3DRender::QTextureLoader(objectEntity);
        Qt3DExtras::QTextureMaterial *material = new Qt3DExtras::QTextureMaterial(objectEntity);
        textureLoader->setSource(QUrl("qrc:/Models/GreenBox.png"));
        material->setTexture(textureLoader);
        objectEntity->addComponent(material);
```

I do not have any error messages.

I tried DAE-object:

[image: 2870d4ad-ef4d-4984-884d-b7bf65bb4da6-image.png]

GreenBox.dae

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<COLLADA xmlns="http://www.collada.org/2005/11/COLLADASchema" version="1.4.1">
  <asset>
    <contributor>
      <author>Blender User</author>
      <authoring_tool>Blender 2.67.0 r57141</authoring_tool>
    </contributor>
    <created>2021-08-21T16:56:51</created>
    <modified>2021-08-21T16:56:51</modified>
    <unit name="meter" meter="1"/>
    <up_axis>Z_UP</up_axis>
  </asset>
  <library_images/>
  <library_effects>
    <effect id="Material-effect">
      <profile_COMMON>
        <technique sid="common">
          <phong>
            <emission>
              <color sid="emission">0 0 0 1</color>
            </emission>
            <ambient>
              <color sid="ambient">0 0 0 1</color>
            </ambient>
            <diffuse>
              <color sid="diffuse">0.64 0.64 0.64 1</color>
            </diffuse>
            <specular>
              <color sid="specular">0.5 0.5 0.5 1</color>
            </specular>
            <shininess>
              <float sid="shininess">50</float>
            </shininess>
            <index_of_refraction>
              <float sid="index_of_refraction">1</float>
            </index_of_refraction>
          </phong>
        </technique>
        <extra>
          <technique profile="GOOGLEEARTH">
            <double_sided>1</double_sided>
          </technique>
        </extra>
      </profile_COMMON>
      <extra><technique profile="MAX3D"><double_sided>1</double_sided></technique></extra>
    </effect>
  </library_effects>
  <library_materials>
    <material id="Material-material" name="Material">
      <instance_effect url="#Material-effect"/>
    </material>
  </library_materials>
  <library_geometries>
    <geometry id="Cube-mesh" name="Cube">
      <mesh>
        <source id="Cube-mesh-positions">
          <float_array id="Cube-mesh-positions-array" count="24">1 1 -1 1 -1 -1 -1 -0.9999998 -1 -0.9999997 1 -1 1 0.9999995 1 0.9999994 -1.000001 1 -1 -0.9999997 1 -1 1 1</float_array>
          <technique_common>
            <accessor source="#Cube-mesh-positions-array" count="8" stride="3">
              <param name="X" type="float"/>
              <param name="Y" type="float"/>
              <param name="Z" type="float"/>
            </accessor>
          </technique_common>
        </source>
        <source id="Cube-mesh-normals">
          <float_array id="Cube-mesh-normals-array" count="36">0 0 -1 0 0 1 1 -5.66244e-7 -2.38419e-7 0 -1 -2.98023e-7 -1 2.38419e-7 -1.19209e-7 2.08616e-7 1 2.38419e-7 0 0 -1 0 0 1 1 0 3.27826e-7 -4.76837e-7 -1 0 -1 2.08616e-7 -1.49012e-7 2.68221e-7 1 1.78814e-7</float_array>
          <technique_common>
            <accessor source="#Cube-mesh-normals-array" count="12" stride="3">
              <param name="X" type="float"/>
              <param name="Y" type="float"/>
              <param name="Z" type="float"/>
            </accessor>
          </technique_common>
        </source>
        <source id="Cube-mesh-map-0">
          <float_array id="Cube-mesh-map-0-array" count="72">0.3991582 0.6954766 0.3991585 0.4875001 0.6071346 0.6954768 0.3991591 0.07154691 0.6071359 0.07154715 0.6071354 0.2795239 0.3991582 0.6954766 0.3991582 0.903453 0.1911818 0.9034531 0.3991585 0.4875001 0.399159 0.2795235 0.607135 0.4875004 0.815111 0.6954768 0.815111 0.9034532 0.6071346 0.6954768 0.3991582 0.903453 0.3991582 0.6954766 0.6071346 0.6954768 0.3991585 0.4875001 0.607135 0.4875004 0.6071346 0.6954768 0.399159 0.2795235 0.3991591 0.07154691 0.6071354 0.2795239 0.1911819 0.6954766 0.3991582 0.6954766 0.1911818 0.9034531 0.399159 0.2795235 0.6071354 0.2795239 0.607135 0.4875004 0.815111 0.9034532 0.6071346 0.9034532 0.6071346 0.6954768 0.6071346 0.9034532 0.3991582 0.903453 0.6071346 0.6954768</float_array>
          <technique_common>
            <accessor source="#Cube-mesh-map-0-array" count="36" stride="2">
              <param name="S" type="float"/>
              <param name="T" type="float"/>
            </accessor>
          </technique_common>
        </source>
        <vertices id="Cube-mesh-vertices">
          <input semantic="POSITION" source="#Cube-mesh-positions"/>
        </vertices>
        <polylist material="Material-material" count="12">
          <input semantic="VERTEX" source="#Cube-mesh-vertices" offset="0"/>
          <input semantic="NORMAL" source="#Cube-mesh-normals" offset="1"/>
          <input semantic="TEXCOORD" source="#Cube-mesh-map-0" offset="2" set="0"/>
          <vcount>3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 </vcount>
          <p>0 0 0 1 0 1 3 0 2 4 1 3 7 1 4 6 1 5 0 2 6 4 2 7 5 2 8 1 3 9 5 3 10 2 3 11 2 4 12 6 4 13 3 4 14 4 5 15 0 5 16 3 5 17 1 6 18 2 6 19 3 6 20 5 7 21 4 7 22 6 7 23 1 8 24 0 8 25 5 8 26 5 9 27 6 9 28 2 9 29 6 10 30 7 10 31 3 10 32 7 11 33 4 11 34 3 11 35</p>
        </polylist>
      </mesh>
      <extra><technique profile="MAYA"><double_sided>1</double_sided></technique></extra>
    </geometry>
  </library_geometries>
  <library_controllers/>
  <library_visual_scenes>
    <visual_scene id="Scene" name="Scene">
      <node id="Cube" name="Cube" type="NODE">
        <matrix sid="transform">1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1</matrix>
        <instance_geometry url="#Cube-mesh">
          <bind_material>
            <technique_common>
              <instance_material symbol="Material-material" target="#Material-material"/>
            </technique_common>
          </bind_material>
        </instance_geometry>
      </node>
    </visual_scene>
  </library_visual_scenes>
  <scene>
    <instance_visual_scene url="#Scene"/>
  </scene>
</COLLADA>
```

and OBJ-object:

[image: 41e17fd1-0c23-4c42-a375-641bd90ced14-image.png]

GreenBox.obj

```
# Blender v2.93.5 OBJ File: ''
# www.blender.org
mtllib GreenBox.mtl
o Cube_Cube.001
v 1.000000 -1.000000 -1.000000
v 1.000000 -1.000000 1.000000
v -1.000000 -1.000000 1.000000
v -1.000000 -1.000000 -1.000000
v 1.000000 1.000000 -1.000000
v 0.999999 1.000000 1.000001
v -1.000000 1.000000 1.000000
v -1.000000 1.000000 -1.000000
vt 0.399158 0.695477
vt 0.399159 0.487500
vt 0.607135 0.695477
vt 0.399159 0.071547
vt 0.607136 0.071547
vt 0.607135 0.279524
vt 0.399158 0.903453
vt 0.191182 0.903453
vt 0.399159 0.279523
vt 0.607135 0.487500
vt 0.815111 0.695477
vt 0.815111 0.903453
vt 0.191182 0.695477
vt 0.607135 0.903453
vn 0.0000 -1.0000 0.0000
vn 0.0000 1.0000 0.0000
vn 1.0000 -0.0000 0.0000
vn -0.0000 -0.0000 1.0000
vn -1.0000 -0.0000 -0.0000
vn 0.0000 0.0000 -1.0000
usemtl Material.001
s off
f 1/1/1 2/2/1 4/3/1
f 5/4/2 8/5/2 7/6/2
f 1/1/3 5/7/3 6/8/3
f 2/2/4 6/9/4 3/10/4
f 3/11/5 7/12/5 4/3/5
f 5/7/6 1/1/6 4/3/6
f 2/2/1 3/10/1 4/3/1
f 6/9/2 5/4/2 7/6/2
f 2/13/3 1/1/3 6/8/3
f 6/9/4 7/6/4 3/10/4
f 7/12/5 8/14/5 4/3/5
f 8/14/6 5/7/6 4/3/6
```

GreenBox.mtl

```
# Blender MTL File: 'None'
# Material Count: 1

newmtl Material.001
Ns 225.000000
Ka 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000
Kd 0.640000 0.640000 0.640000
Ks 0.500000 0.500000 0.500000
Ke 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
Ni 1.000000
d 1.000000
illum 2
```

This is my texture:

[image: GreenBox.png]

My source code:

.pro

```
QT       += 3dcore 3dlogic 3dextras 3dinput
```

I have all code in one `main.cpp` file:

main.cpp

```
#ifdef _WIN32
#include <windows.h>
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) DWORD NvOptimusEnablement = 0x00000001;
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) DWORD AmdPowerXpressRequestHighPerformance = 0x00000001;
#endif

#include <QtCore/QDebug>
#include <QtGui/QGuiApplication>
#include <Qt3DExtras/Qt3DWindow>
#include <Qt3DExtras/QOrbitCameraController>
#include <Qt3DExtras/QTextureMaterial>
#include <Qt3DCore/QEntity>
#include <Qt3DCore/QTransform>
#include <Qt3DRender/QCamera>
#include <Qt3DRender/QPointLight>
#include <Qt3DRender/QSceneLoader>
#include <Qt3DRender/QTexture>

class Window : public Qt3DExtras::Qt3DWindow
{
public:
    Window()
    {
        setTitle("Texture for 3D model");
        resize(400, 400);

        Qt3DCore::QEntity *rootEntity = new Qt3DCore::QEntity();

        // Lighting
        Qt3DCore::QEntity *lightEntity = new Qt3DCore::QEntity(rootEntity);
        Qt3DRender::QPointLight *pointLight = new Qt3DRender::QPointLight(lightEntity);
        Qt3DCore::QTransform *lightTransform = new Qt3DCore::QTransform(lightEntity);
        lightTransform->setTranslation(QVector3D(20.f, 25.f, 30.f));
        lightEntity->addComponent(pointLight);
        lightEntity->addComponent(lightTransform);

        // 3D Model
        Qt3DCore::QEntity *objectEntity = new Qt3DCore::QEntity(rootEntity);
        Qt3DRender::QSceneLoader *sceneLoader = new Qt3DRender::QSceneLoader(objectEntity);
//        sceneLoader->setSource(QUrl("qrc:/Models/GreenBox.obj"));
        sceneLoader->setSource(QUrl("qrc:/Models/GreenBox.dae"));
        objectEntity->addComponent(sceneLoader);
        Qt3DCore::QTransform *objectTransform = new Qt3DCore::QTransform(objectEntity);
        objectTransform->setScale(10.f);
        objectEntity->addComponent(objectTransform);

        Qt3DRender::QTextureLoader *textureLoader = new Qt3DRender::QTextureLoader(objectEntity);
        Qt3DExtras::QTextureMaterial *material = new Qt3DExtras::QTextureMaterial(objectEntity);
        textureLoader->setSource(QUrl("qrc:/Models/GreenBox.png"));
        material->setTexture(textureLoader);
        objectEntity->addComponent(material);

        // Camera
        Qt3DRender::QCamera *camera = this->camera();
        camera->lens()->setPerspectiveProjection(
                    60.f, (float) this->width() / this->height(), 0.1f, 500.0f);
        camera->setPosition(QVector3D(30.0f, 30.0f, 30.f));
        camera->setViewCenter(QVector3D(0.f, 0.f, 0.f));

        Qt3DExtras::QOrbitCameraController *cameraController =
                new Qt3DExtras::QOrbitCameraController(rootEntity);
        cameraController->setCamera(camera);
        cameraController->setLookSpeed(180.f);
        cameraController->setLinearSpeed(50.f);

        this->setRootEntity(rootEntity);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    Window w;
    w.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: The SceneLoader already creates one or more material(s) for the loaded scene. For your material to take effect you need to inspect/traverse the loaded scene and replace those materials with yours.